# PHP status of the function

Tags: php

I add to the file `status.txt` a `1` if a script works and `0` if not.

```
<?php

if (!file_exists("status.txt"))
    file_put_contents("status.txt", 0); //Create status.txt with value "0"

//Read "status.txt"
$status = file("status.txt");

if($status[0]!=1)
    start();
else{
    echo "already working...";
}

function start()
{
    file_put_contents("status.txt", 1);//Start work
    sleep(10);
    file_put_contents("status.txt", 0);//End work
}
```

If I run script, in file will be recorded `1`.
Than if I run in another tab same script must be echo, but function `start()` runs.

Why? While function work, file `status.txt` really contains "`1`".

Comment: Actually, I just tested this exact same code and it works as advertised :)  maybe your problem is trying to run the script from two different locations? (then the `status.txt` file would get created in two different directories)

Comment: Your script looks right. In fact, I just ran it (in console), and it works as you expected. Perhaps your system configuration is caching the file content. What are your OS/webserver ?

Comment: Im using denwer om my PC

Answer (score 0):

Second time when you the run the script , the `start()` runs because... the `if (!file_exists("status.txt"))` becomes `false` (since the status.txt file exists!!) and `file_put_contents("status.txt", 0);` will not be executed either.

But `$status = file("status.txt");` will be executed and `$status[0]` holds 0 which was prewritten by the same script which ran before. Since 0 not equals 1, `start()` runs up.

So as per this script everytime the `start()` will be executed.

Comment: While func start() works, status.txt contains 1. In that moment i run another tab with same script.